# Iterated exponential function

Tags: special-functions

Is it possible to infinitely differentiably extend the function defined as $f(x+1,a)=e^{f(x,a)}$, $f(0,a)=a$ to non-integers?

What I’m trying to do is derive a sort of «half logarithm», a function that if applied twice gives the natural logarithm.

Comment: [Here's a question from MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12081/does-the-exponential-function-have-a-square-root) about half exponentials which you may be interested in.

Comment: I am aware that the domain should have a left bound; for example, in the case where $a=1$, the domain is $(-2,\infty)$.

Comment: You might be interested in [Carleman matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleman_matrix)...

Comment: Thanks! I understand that Carleman matrices map function composition to matrix multiplication, but how exactly am I supposed to multiply a fractional number of matrices together?

Comment: Is it supposed to read $f(x+1,a)=\exp(f(x,a))$?

Comment: Yes, it’s fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, such a "half logarithm" and its inverse "half exponential" functions have been explored in the past.   There are multiple ways to define them.  The half-logarithm's domain exists only above a certain value.

The best, as in being smoothest,  and computationally feasible, is probably by G. Szekeres, "Fractional Iteration of Exponentially Growing Functions" in J. Australian Math. Soc. vol 2 p 301 (1961).

An older work based on fixed points in the complex plane is: Hellmuth Kneser. Reel analytische Losungen der Gleichung φ(φ(x)) = ex und verwandter
Funktionalgleichungen. J. f. Reine Agnew. Math. 187, page 56, page 56 (1950).

Then there's my own invention based on symmetries, published in an obscure journal with many typos: Daren Wilson, Fractional Order Arithmetic, part I. J.Undergraduate Mathematics 12 (2), page 51 (1980).
Fractional Order Arithmetic, part II. J.Undergraduate Mathematics 13, page
(?) (1981)

Comment: Is there some sort of iterative algorithm to calculate the Szekeres function?

Comment: Yes. While not complicated, it's hard to describe in full here. We use function g(x)=exp(x)-1, which can be fractionally iterated using a power series expansion. Starting with some x, you repeatedly apply exp() until you get a "large" value. Then apply the inverse of g(x) repeatedly until you get a value small enough to apply a truncated power series to good approximation.  Then go back up with g(x) and down with the inverse of exp(x), matching in count to undo what was done before.  This is too sketchy for numerical work; see the Szekeres paper for more.

Comment: BTW, I'm writing a paper explaining all three methods in more detail.  The more I get nudged to finish it, the sooner it'll get done!

Comment: @DarenW I wonder if - 4 years later - your paper has emerged? I would love to read it - is there a link?

Comment: It's pretty much done, but I'd like to add a few more plots.  Then again, maybe I have enough.   I can always put additional plots up on my website, make a Youtube video, whatever.  Heck, I might was pop that PDF up on my website. I'll be unlikely to have time to refine it fully, and the main part is good.

Comment: FWIW, my paper is done, but unpublished anywhere. Python code for numerical work and a PDF of the paper are at Github, https://github.com/darenw/FRITEXP